# django-taggit: make the tags not required in the admin

Tags: python, django, django-taggit

I've started using django-taggit and it seems to fit the bill. But for me there is still an issue with the admin site:

I included the `tags` attribute in the ModelAdmin like this:

```
class MyModel(db.models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tags = TaggableManager()

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('name', 'tags')
        }),
    )
```

And everything goes as expected. But when I edit a model in the admin, I get an error, if the TagField is empty. The form seems to be happy with just a blank, and that results in no tags being saved (as expected). But an empty tag field triggers the error.

What can I do?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Did you try `tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)`?

> blank – Controls whether this field is
>   required

... at least that's what [the docs](http://django-taggit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#TaggableManager) say.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but TaggableManager(blank=True) doesn't work on a model I updated and migrated. Had to add this to the admin form (`forms.ModelForm`).

```
self.fields['tags'].required = False
```