# Integrity error stops Django before save_m2m()

Tags: python, django, save, m2m

I am trying to save a m2m field in Django.  I am receiving `a NOT NULL constraint failed:  posts_listing.tags`.  I am using django-taggit for the tags field.

Here is the save function I have overridden in my form.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['commit'] = False
    obj = super(ListingForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    obj.created_by = self.request.user
    obj.save()
    obj.save_m2m()
```

In the traceback it seems that I am being thrown the error before being the `save_m2m()`.  The error occurs at `obj.save()`.  Before that, however I see that my data for this field, `u'tags': [u'six']`, is being passed in at the `form.save()` I have in my view.

I have read the other answers regarding `save_m2m()`, but can't seem to kill this integrity error.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

I have also tried putting the save_m2m() in my views, after I call a form.save() .  Like this:

forms.py:

```
class ListingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        return super(ListingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['commit'] = False
        obj = super(ListingForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        obj.created_by = self.request.user
        obj.save()
```

views.py:

```
def add_listing(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)


    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ListingForm(request.POST, request=request)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            return thanks(request)
```

Comment: Please show the actual error. There's no such thing as a NOT NULL constraint for a ManyToManyField, as an M2M is not a field but an entry in a linking table.

Comment: Ok, I see. My error says `NOT NULL constraint failed: posts_listing.tags`.  I will edit the post.

Comment: Figured it out, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320686/django-taggit-make-the-tags-not-required-in-the-admin  this answer worked, I just had not run the migration after making blank=True for the field